# Where to get a Compiled "Windows Ribbon for WinForms 2.2"?

Tags: winforms, ribbon

I am just wondering whether anyone knows where I can get a compiled version of [Windows Ribbon for WinForms](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com) 2.2? I can only download the source from the website and as I don't have the Windows 7 SDK (and can't download) I can't compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could download the DLL (you can't), it is not going to help you.  To create your own ribbon for use in your own application you must create a ribbon markup file.  That file needs to be compiled by UICC.EXE, a tool that is only available in the Windows 7 SDK.  Without that tool, you cannot create your own ribbon.

Downloading the SDK is required.  Note that the SDK version that comes with VS2010 is not good enough, it is a sub-set of the SDK and does not include uicc.exe